# Best approach for detecting human in a picture

Tags: cnn

I am trying to detect if an image contains human or not. I will use CNN for this. I am planning to make a dataset like following.

```
Train 
     human (contains 2000 or more human image)
     other object (contains 2000 or more non human image)

Test 
     human (contains 500)
     other object (contains 500 )
```

I am planning to use keras and I will train data from directory .

Is there any alternative approach ? Because I am having trouble with collecting human and non human object image.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with skin disease classification. You can see the question and its answers too [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/49366/what-are-the-possible-ways-to-detect-skin-while-classifying-diseases).  Gathering a dataset of human pictures could be easy but that of non-human could be nearly impossible ( non-human objects are a huge set of objects )

**Solution:**

We can use a Siamese Convolutional Neural Network. I have written a blog on it. See [here](https://medium.com/predict/face-recognition-from-scratch-using-siamese-networks-and-tensorflow-df03e32f8cd0). They perform one-shot learning and are best when we have smaller datasets.

> A standard CNN tries to classify whether the pictures belongs to any one of the classes -> (HUMAN, NON_HUMAN ). The Siamese CNN outputs a similarity score rather than class probabilities. A standard CNN learns to classify and on the other hand, a Siamese CNN learns to differentiate images.

**How does it work? ( In the context of your task )**

Suppose I have an input image $x$. This is our input for the Siamese CNN. I have two more images, say $f$ and $g$. Image $f$ belongs to class 1 ( HUMAN ) whereas $g$ belongs to CLASS 2 ( NON-HUMAN ). The Siamese CNN takes in 2 images as input and outputs how similar they are.

$ Siamese( x , f ) = 0.678$

$ Siamese( x , g ) = 0.987$

$Clearly, \space Siamese( x , f ) < Siamese( x , g )$

Therefore, the image belongs to CLASS 2. You can find its other advantages on the blog. Hope this helps.